# Create columns looping through 2 vectors

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I'm trying to create a function that will create new labeled indicator columns for a select group of columns in a data set.

```
# Data Set
A = as.factor(c(0,2,1,0))
B = as.factor(c(2,NA,1,0))
C = as.factor(c(1,0,NA,0))
D = as.factor(c(NA,2,0,1))
dat = data.table(A, B, C, D)
```

Currently I'm doing this for each column that I want:

```
# What I'm currently doing (expected output of loop matches these columns)
attach(dat)
        VAR = B
        dat$b.test[VAR == "0"] <- "0"
        dat$b.test[VAR == "1" | VAR == "2"] <- "1"

        VAR = C
        dat$c.test[VAR == "0"] <- "0"
        dat$c.test[VAR == "1" | VAR == "2"] <- "1"

        VAR = D
        dat$d.test[VAR == "0"] <- "0"
        dat$d.test[VAR == "1" | VAR == "2"] <- "1"
detach(dat)
```

It seems like I should be able to create a for loop that will run over a vector containing all the columns that I want the logic to execute on (B, C, D) and call a new name from another vector (b2, c2, d2) at the same location within each vector.

Attempt method 1

```
# Failed method 1
attach(dat)
        new.var = c(b2, c2, d2)
        cur.var = c(B, C, D)
        l = length(cur.var)

        for(i in 1:l){
                X = cur.var[i]
                VAR = cur.var[i]
                dat$X[VAR == "0"] <- "0"
                dat$X[VAR == "1" | VAR == "2"] <- "1"
        }
detach(dat)
```

Results in new column X

Attempt method 2

```
# Failed method 2
        new.var = c(dat$b2, dat$c2, dat$d2)
        cur.var = c(dat$B, dat$C, dat$D)
        l = length(cur.var)
for(i in 1:l){
        new.var[i] = ifelse(new.var[i] == "0", "0",
                            ifelse(new.var[i] == "1" | "2", "1", NA)
                            )
}
```

Is there a different method to try and do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide us a df with your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a loop. You can use the .SD variable to iterate over columns. For example

```
change<-c("B","C","D")

myfun <- function(x) ifelse(x==0, "0", "1")
dat[,paste0(change,".test") := Map(myfun, .SD), .SDcols=change]

#    A  B  C  D B.test C.test D.test
# 1: 0  2  1 NA      1      1     NA
# 2: 2 NA  0  2     NA      0      1
# 3: 1  1 NA  0      1     NA      0
# 4: 0  0  0  1      0      0      1
```

Comment: The OP had `data.table` in their example. Where would use use `as.character(as.interger(x))`? 2's should become 1's as well in the sample code.